# Save current line in variable

Tags: vim

How can I read the current line (where the cursor is) and save it to a variable in VimScript?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
let lineText = getline('.')
```

See `:h getline()`…

If you only want the number:

```
let lineNumber = line('.')
```